# How to remove a list from a view if a specific counter is met

Tags: 2007, list, list-view

Here's my scenario.

SharePoint 2007 Standard Sp3

I've been tasked with creating a room booking system for a series of seminars.  Each seminar has a specific headcount.  The end vision is that we create something with a SharePoint calendar with two views.  One view will show seminar time slots available available and the second will show one that aren't available.  This is intended to be a self booking system.

The differences between the views will be the head count.  If headcount < 15, keep in one view, if headcount => 15 kep in another view.

I've created a calendar, with the custom form.  Now, I'm wondering on the best way to capture page edits.  This could be via a column, custom column or workflow variable.

Any commentary or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about presenting that in new Sharepoint calculated column -

```
=IF([HeadCount] > 15,"YES","NO")
```

With [HeadCount] being the original value of your Headcount column.

Then you should be able to set your views based off that new calculated value.